# Cygwin login fails using WinSCP under restored MS Windows Sysprep Image

Tags: cygwin, winscp, sysprep

`Cygwin` login fails using `WinSCP` under restored MS Windows `Sysprep` Image .

Any clue why is it?

Comment: What does *"login fails"* mean? Error message? Log file? Anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problems but I found information that might be helpful.

> Connection established
>
> Incorrect RSA1 identifier
>
> Could not load "/home/abcd/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key

```
$ ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 4000.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/abcd/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
```